# how to force 1440x900 resolution on acer al1702w lcd monitor

Tags: windows-xp, resolution, intel-graphics

i have acer al1702w lcd monitor in my office..

somehow i restarted the system using the reset button as the os stoped responding..

since then the 1440x900 resolution option in the display settings is not appearing..
the intel graphocs is  82945G...
and as always the h/w guys at the office are of no help.. they start blurting out their theories that this the best resolution... even though  i show them that the max resolution 
for the monitor is indeed 1440x900..
and its not that the 82945g cant handle it... as it was working before..

i installed the latest drivers for this graphics but still im not finding that option...

how to force 1440x900 resolution...
oh tes the os ix xp pro sp2
Thanks..

Comment: Go to Device Manager and see if the display adapter is loaded

Answer (score 1):

Warning: the advice below could violate your company policies and or leave your PC unusable. If you don't know how to do this get someone that does to do it for you.

If the resolution doesn't show the video driver needs to be updated or reinstalled. Older drivers will not offer 16:10 resolutions.

I'm guessing on the restart a file got corrupted or plug and play decided a different driver was more appropriate for your "video card".

If your PC is a Dell go to support.dell.com and download the graphics driver for your PC (same goes for HP or any other big name PC). If you have no other option you can try http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/graphics/intel945g and work your way to downloading a driver.

Of course if this is a home PC and it has a PCIe slot I'd highly suggest you buy the cheapest ATI 4xxx or 5xxx card you can and use it instead of the Intel graphics.

At this point a 4350 costs about $35 and a 5450 costs about $45. Either one would be a huge step up from 945G integrated graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [PowerStrip](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm) to force that resolution for your monitor.

Comment: i tried to use it already but couldnt do it... can u guide hw to use powerstrip software?
Thanks.

Comment: take a look in this link:
http://forums.entechtaiwan.com/index.php?topic=24.0

Answer (score 0):

The Acer ali702w is a sensitive monitor that must use its original cable (i.e. the one that came with it) to connect to computers.

Disconnect your cable from both the PC and the LCD monitor, put the end that used to be in the monitor into the PC and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

ftp://ftp2.acer-euro.com/monitor/lcd/AL1702Wv%20Vista%20WHQL%20Driver.zip

Download this and install. If you don't know how to install, just google "how to install drivers manually".. I solved the same issue after searching for hours..

P.S. I know that the question is old, but its the first search result from google search and this will help others with similar problems.